# IPython equivalent to Clojure find-doc?

Tags: python, clojure, documentation, ipython, read-eval-print-loop

In Clojure repl, when forget the exact function name, I can use `find-doc` to list all functions whose documentation or name contains the name I'm looking for. For example:

```
user=> (xor 1 2)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: xor in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init4743234309821191777.clj:1:1) 

user=> (find-doc "xor")
-------------------------
clojure.core/bit-xor
([x y] [x y & more])
  Bitwise exclusive or
nil

user=> (bit-xor 1 2)
3
```

How to do the same thing in IPython repl?

Or what's the Pythonic way to search functions in repl?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google 'python xor'  gives me (several choices down) an official reference page

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html

page find in that takes me to

```
5.8. Binary bitwise operations
...
xor_expr ::=  and_expr | xor_expr "^" and_expr
...
The ^ operator yields the bitwise XOR (exclusive OR) of its arguments, which must be plain or long integers. The arguments are converted to a common type.
```

That page has a search box.  If I type `xor`, I get links to 16 pages.

I see for example `operator.xor`

which if I do, in Ipython

```
import operator
operator.xor?

In [193]: operator.xor??
Type:        builtin_function_or_method
String form: <built-in function xor>
Docstring:   xor(a, b) -- Same as a ^ b.
```

`operator.x<tab>` would also show `operator.xor`.

`x<tab>` in Ipython does not help because there isn't a builtin function called `xor...`.    Since this is implemented as an operator, search will be different from something that is a function.

I use the tab completion alot, and the `?` and `??` to look at the docs for a function and its code (if in Python).  As far as I know `Ipython` does not have links to a general `Python` documentation.

Since I work a lot with `numpy`, I could also search for 'numpy xor', and get links to the `numpy` documentation for `bitwise_xor` and `logical_xor`.

```
np.bit<tab>
```

leads me to

```
np.bitwise_xor? 
<docs for ufunc using the ^ operator>
```

`np.logical_xor` shows me a elementwise array operation.

Comment: Which means there isn't a strict equivalent to Clojure find-doc. Instead, we use Google to find functions, isn't it?

Comment: I glanced at the `find-doc` code.  It collects all the docs in the 'namespace' and prints the ones that match the 'regex'.  Nothing obscure about that.  Python has a `help` function (I used `ipython ??` instead), that imports `pydoc`, which may have other tools that may be of interest.